# Как получить название выбранного элемента из listView?

Tags: c#

Здравствуй дорогой ХешКод, у меня воникла проблемка... вот в listBox'e такого не было, а вот в listView есть, у меня есть картиник которые хранятся в listView, и так же под каждой из них написан путь, гдн она расположена, так вот мне надо понять как сделать так чтобы когда я выбирал ту или иную картинку в textBox1 заисывался этот путь...я пробовал так

```
textBox1.Text = listView.SelectedItems.ToString();
```

Однако он мне выдаёт совсем не то что нужно, помогите пожалуйста в этой ситуации.

Answer (score 3):

```
textBox1.Text = listView.SelectedItems[0].Text;
```

Это если у Вас мультиселект выключен, или Вам нужен только первый выделенный. В противном случае можно перебрать в цикле. А перед этим хорошо было бы проверить есть ли вообще выделенные итемы:

```
if (listView.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Да спасибо, но не нужен не только самый первый элемент, а любой который будет выделен.

Comment: Вам же все ответили: перебрать в цикле, если выделено несколько. Есть у вас выделен только один элемент, то этот код сработает верно.

Answer (score 0):

```
string s = listView.SelectedItems.Aggregate<string>((r, s) => r + s.Text);
```